# Jaws screen reader scrolling function issue when reading pdf

Tags: accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, tagged-pdf

when using Jaws screen reader (version 15 on windows 7) to read the contents of a 3 page tagged pdf, it reads the content correctly but it scrolls down to the last page once it starts reading the contents of the first page. The pdf contains a single table that spreads on three pages with repeated header and footer. As i said the contents of all three pages are being read correctly. Also when using the read out function of both acrobat reader and acrobat Pro 9 the issue does not appear. Moreover accessibility tests performed on the pdf using acrobat pro 9, did not indicate any issue with the pdf being tagged incorrectly.  Could this be a bug with Jaws? Or is there a particular setting i must activate ?
I would greatly appreciate any ideas or suggestions.

Edit: I removed the header/footer but did not notice any change in the behaviour (automatically scrolls to the last page).

Edit 2: I tried using NVDA screen reader but even though  it reads the pdf correctly, the pdf does not scroll down to the next page when the reader  finishes the content of the first page,but continues to display the first page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question is now four years old. Does the issue still exist or has it been solved in newer versions of Jaws?